# i don't know why my dev c++ #include doesn't work

Tags: c, dev-c++

the #include doesn't work in my dev c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("ssss");
}
```

the #include doesn't work in my dev c

here's the message [error]

"printf" was not declared in this scope

i deleted dev c and install it over and over again but it remains the same

this situation happens when I practice File io

Comment: are you sure you don't have `stdio.h` by happenstance in the same directory? Is this an actual copy-paste?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code, you should check your compiler options.

From the menu bar, go; **Tools -> Compiler Options -> Directories**

I am using MinGW64 on Windows Platform. Here is my configurations, you can check and compare with your configurations.

[image: C Includes]

[image: Libraries]

**Edit:** Since you have the same configuration with me, you should check whether do you have `"stdio.h"` header file in the linked directory or not.

1. Firstly, under the **"Libraries"** tab, you will see some file locations where **MinGW64\lib** located. In my device, the location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib`
2. Once you are in the **lib** folder, follow the next paths as **gcc -> x86_64-w64-mingw32 -> 4.9.2 -> include -> ssp**. So in final, the path you will reach should be something like this; `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\ssp`. Note that, the folder names can change up to your device or the version of MinGW64.
3. Once you reach the folder location which I mentioned above, all you have to do is check whether the **stdio.h** header file is in the folder or not. If it is not there, you should add it to there.

Comment: is as same as u

Comment: Okey, if it is the same then follow the next steps in my answer after I will edit it.

Comment: i follow the steps and the stdio is in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\ssp